# Identify whether user running msi installer is admin or not

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-installer, setup-project

I want to add functionality to my visual studio 2008 setup project such that it will pop up a message box saying the user running the installer is administrator or non admin user. Is there any way to do this where I parse some command string and if there is any specific argument I will pop up an appropriate message box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Privileged property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370852%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  indicates whether the installation is performed in the context of elevated privileges. You can use this in a conditional expression ([Conditional Statement Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368012%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) in the [LaunchCondition table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369752%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This is found in Visual Studio Setup Projects by right clicking the project and selecting View | Launch Conditions.